# Accessing list of dictionaries within a dictionary in python

Tags: python-2.7

So lets see how bad i messed this up 
This is what is supposed to look like

```
Students
1 - MICHAEL JORDAN - 13
2 - JOHN ROSALES - 11
3 - MARK GUILLEN - 11
4 - KB TONEL - 7
Instructors
1 - MICHAEL CHOI - 11
2 - MARTIN PURYEAR - 13
```

How ever the two extra arrays are throwing me for a loop. I called the for loop for the first one thus having students and instructors.  Then I called the keys and value.  Could some one please look at this and point me in the right direction to fix this mess

```
users = {
 'Students': [
     {'first_name':  'Michael', 'last_name' : 'Jordan'},
     {'first_name' : 'John', 'last_name' : 'Rosales'},
     {'first_name' : 'Mark', 'last_name' : 'Guillen'},
     {'first_name' : 'KB', 'last_name' : 'Tonel'}
  ],
 'Instructors': [
     {'first_name' : 'Michael', 'last_name' : 'Choi'},
     {'first_name' : 'Martin', 'last_name' : 'Puryear'}
  ]
 }



for i in users:

    for i in Students:
        print ([i['first_name'], i['last_name']] , + len([i['first_name'], i['last_name']




    for i in Instructors:
        print ([i['first_name'], i['last_name']] , + len([i['first_name'], i['last_name'0]
```

Comment: What is the exact error, you are presented with?
You should not override the variable `i` in the inner loop.

Comment: `print` is not a function in python 2.x but a statement (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) – thus no parentheses.
Closing parens missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are trying to override the value of `i` with your loops, you should avoid doing it, also when you just use `for i in users:` you are iterating only through the **keys** of dict `users`, you can use dict.items() or dict.iteritems() to access both key, value pair in the dictionary.

And here is your updated code, just in case.

```
 for usr, info in users.iteritems():
     print "{}".format(usr)
     for i, _info in enumerate(info, 1):
         name = "{first_name} {last_name}".format(**_info).upper()
         print "{} - {} - {}".format(i, name, len(name)-1)
```

I will leave it to you to understand the code and the builtin functions being used in the code.